# たら - past/future vs future/future

Tags: conditionals

Consider the following two sentences:

> 1. If you **eat** that, you will get sick. (you haven't eaten it yet)

> 2. If you **ate** that, you will get sick. (you have eaten it already, but you still feel OK)

My understanding is that both are translated as

> これを食べたら病気になる

Is there are way to differentiate between 1 and 2?

Comment: "If you ate that" isn't necessarily something you've already done.  It could be subjunctive counter-factual and mean, we know you aren't going to eat it, but if you were to, then....

Comment: @A.Ellett - Does the second second sentence, as it is (with *will* instead of *would*), mean これを食べたのなら病気になる?

Comment: @aguijonazo I'm not sure.  Hence why I'm not answering the question.  But, I just wanted to point out that even in the English, there is ambiguity in what exactly is being said with the second sentence.  I'm a bit confused by your suggestion:  I'm not sure what's being expressed by 食べたのなら.  If this is the explanatory の, then perhaps that captures what the OP is trying to get at.

Comment: The issue is really that the subjective in English has declined significantly in usage and this grammar is not taught in schools unless you take a course in Latin, ancient Greek, or Sanskrit.  The grammar of the subjunctive has gotten very weak.  So, I don't think the difference of *will* vs *would* conveys much anymore.

Comment: @A.Ellett - Students don’t need to go back to those old languages. They can just look around and observe what Spanish speakers are saying…

Comment: @aguijonazo That is true.  (Or French or German).  But in my high school Latin classes, a lot of attention was spent on understanding how to properly express the subjunctive in English.  In my German class, the subjunctive was taught, but very little effort was expended on whether we understood the subjunctive in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use たら for the first sentence.

> これを食べたら病気になる。

Speakers in some regions might use と.

> これを食べると病気になる。

But it sounds to me like the causal relationship is already firmly established in the speaker’s mind and the speaker is stating it as a fact rather than a caution to the listener in this particular situation.

What I understand from the second sentence is that the speaker has just learned the listener ate something they didn’t think they should’ve and is stating what they think is likely to happen as a consequence. You can’t use たら in this case as たら places focus on the point of time at which the action of the verb has just completed, but there is no reason to do so in this scenario because it is already known to be a fact that the other person ate the thing. You should use なら.

> これを食べたのなら病気になる。

なら, combined with the explanatory の here, gives the sense of “if the situation is such as I just learned (or as you just explained).” This の is practically mandatory.

You can use たら or と but in these forms.

> これを食べたのだとしたら病気になる。

> これを食べたのだとすると病気になる。

〜とする doesn’t describe an action, so no particular point of time is felt focused even with たら. It’s like saying “supposing …” I would say these two sentences are practically interchangeable. Speakers in different regions might prefer one over the other. Compared to the sentence with なら above, they sound like the speaker hasn’t fully accepted it as a fact yet and is treating it as a supposition.

の in all the sentences above is often contracted to ん in casual speech.

Comment: Beautiful answer.  Thanks for addressing the matter of using both 食べると and としたら.  It seemed to me that 食べたら couldn't be used for the second statement, but I didn't know how to explain that (or even if my intuition was correct).  I really liked the nuances you drew out.  Very helpful.